# Why give $(function () in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I had to keep my some of my javascript functions in a `$(function())` to make it work. But some others worked just fine without placing them inside. What's the difference?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: javascript and jquery are **not** the same

Comment: point Taken @asprin :)

Comment: Why downvote, it's not a bad question.

Comment: Thanks for the support Esa !! M a beginner and Theres a lot to learn in jquery and i just love  what all you could do with it !! :)

Comment: It's a bad question because a) it could have been easily answered with a tiny bit of research and b) questions should be worded and organized in a much better manner to be welcome at SO.

Comment: Hmm.. Thats true. Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends where on the page you put the functions.  Anything that manipulates the DOM (which is most of what jQuery does) should be run after the DOM has loaded, so at the very bottom of your script right before the < /body> closing tag.  If you want it up at the top, you have to put it in that function (called the "document ready function") which waits until after the DOM is loaded to run the code inside it.

Comment: Thats exactly the ans i wanted !! :) the link posted by @Stefan Seemayer also helped a lot !! :)

Comment: Glad to help!  Feel free to check an answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Comment: Sure Dan Goodspeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Any code you put inside $(function()) will only run once the document has fully loaded. This is useful if you want to manipulate the document in javascript/jquery, as you may be relying on certain elements being ready.

e.g. if you want to add an element to a particular div, the div must be loaded before the script will work.

Answer (score 0):

`$(function())` is short hand for `$(document).ready` so it is expected to be execute once document becomes ready so most of the things comes in scope in that time, if you have some function dependent on other libs or dom, better to put it in ready a function without any kind of dependency will work anywhere

Answer (score 0):

`$(function())` as same as `$(document).ready();`

All the statements with in this will be execute when your DOM is fully loaded on browser.
As you mentioned that some code is working So I clarify you that that element on which you are attaching event or doing anything with that may be loaded on browser.
That will be the reason behind it So it is recommend that return all the code inside of `$(document).ready()`. Except function or method definition in the script